# How to generate notifications in Mattermost for all state change in JIRA or Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, jira, mattermost

In the latest(4.9) Mattermost, it provides integration with Gitlab and a Beta plugin for JIRA.

I followed the documents to finish the integration, and it works, I got notifications for the "create", "close" and "reopen" operation.

For the BUG issue, we'd like to make it "Resolved" so that our QA engineer will verify it, then it can be closed, but the "resolve" operation will not trigger any notifications neither in Gitlab nor JIRA.

I tried to use tcpdump to capture the TCP package, and it turns out that JIRA actually has sent the hook message to Mattermost. It seems to be mattermost itself who ignored those events.

Is there any configuration for such things? What can I do to meet our requirements?

BTW, I'm using the Docker preview version of Mattermost server.

Comment: At present, the Mattermost JIRA plugin only supports some actions, which is why you are not seeing messages being posted for all of them. I believe more will be supported in future versions of the plugin.